# When I download an extension for Visual Studio 2019, it doesn't get installed on restart

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

When I download an extension within Visual Studio 2019 IDE, it downloads successfully and gives a message "changes will be scheduled and that the installs will begin when I close all windows". If I close all the open windows in IDE, nothing happens. Also after a restart, I do not see the extension installed.

Comment: Maybe you can try close all windows by `File menu=>Exit` instead of clicking the `X` button, please check if it make some difference:)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT that works. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm editing the answer with some more possible workarounds right now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> changes will be scheduled and that the installs will begin when I
>   close all windows

To close all windows, try going `File menu => Exit` to close VS instead of clicking the `X` button.

Here're some other workarounds I found:

1.Download the extension from [VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) and double-click the xx.vsix file to start installing manually.

2.If the popup doesn't show, find the xx.vsix in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` folder, run it there to install. See [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/390172/view.html).

Of course these are workarounds, however I can't reproduce same issue in my machine. So I guess maybe something is broken in VS or one unknown process interrupts the installation. I suggest we can make sure we're in Admin permission, run a VS repair(or Update VS to latest 16.3.6), and check if one process like cmd(found one similar issue whose cause is about cmd.exe) by task manager...

Hope all above helps if someone meets similar issue :)

Comment: 1.Download the extension from VS Marketplace and double-click the xx.vsix file to start installing manually. This works for me. Thanks!